# How to change main domain content with cPanel

Tags: dns, web, hosting, cpanel

Before I have assigning a main domain for my website, and automatically have put my website content on /home/my_name/public_html/ of course with CPanel's GUI, but currently I want to change or reassign other website to my assigned  main domain, what the best way for practice, whether just replace content of /home/my_name/public_html/ with linux's command or CPanel have elegant way for do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right:

Go to "Parked Domains" in cPanel and enter the other domains you want to point to the same **/home/my_name/public_html/**. All domains will be sharing the same content.

If you want to replace the actual domain, I guess you have to ask your ISP to do it. Cannot be done in cPanel, as far as I know.

Hope this helps.